# SASS/SCSS mixins with multiple outputs

Tags: sass, mixins

For a while now I've been running into a problem with a large site I'm working on.
The main problem is that our site is offered in two languages: English and Chinese.
The Chinese site is also offered from a different domain: domain.com and domain.com.cn

This brings some issues with it in all our CSS work, mainly fonts and another thing is the domains, since images are offered from our CDN we have to put absolute links into our css, but this also means we have to change it for our Chinese site

```
body.en .title { background: url(http://media.domain.com/title.png); }
body.cn .title { background: url(http://media.domain.com.cn/title.png); }
```

The same goes for fonts, the fonts we use for our English version don't support Chinese characters so we use a different font for Chinese characters

```
body.en .title { font-family: "Our English font" }
body.cn .title { font-family: "Our Chinese font" }
```

I'm now wondering if SASS could help with this, at the moment I just have a different file (_cn.scss) that changes all links and fonts, specifically for the Chinese version.

But let's say I have this mixin to output some css for fonts:

```
@mixin font-english($font-size: 16px, $font-weight: 300, $line-height: 22px) {
    font-family: "English font";
    font-size: $font-size;
    font-weight: $font-weight;
    line-height: $line-height;
}

body.en .title { @include font-english(14px, 700, 18px); }
```

Would there be a way to make it automaticly output the Chinese font as well? Right now I have to do this all manually, the same goes for the urls, could I write a mixin that when I use it like

```
body.en .title { @include background(image.png); }
```

it outputs both

```
body.en .title { @include background(http://media.domain.com/image.png); }
```

and

```
body.cn .title { @include background(http://media.domain.com.cn/image.png); }
```

I know this probably isn't possible, but I'm just looking for a better solution, right now I have to go through all the css again and change urls and fonts to the Chinese version.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to use compass, this is actually pretty easy with their [url helpers](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/).

I think what you'd need to do is setup two config groups in `config.rb`, one for the english version and one for the chinese version.

You can set things like the [image url](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/#image-url), and [generated image url](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/#generated-image-url) in the config. Images should then be reference not as `@include background(foo.png)` but as `background: image-url('foo.png')`. When you run your compass task, for the english version of the site, you'd get the urls you specify for english images (what an "english image" is, I have no idea :))

Fonts are slightly different since you're probably working with completely different files. Two approaches you could take:

1) use compass's [font-url helper](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/#font-url) to reference the fonts, similar to the way you would use the image-url helper. The challenge here is that you would presumably need to name the font the same thing because it'd be referenced as `src: font-url('font.woff');`. This might not be exactly what your'e looking for

2) Use a different SASS file for Chinese fonts. With SASS's partials, this shouldn't be *too* much of an issue.

You could basically have all styles as they are, call them through english_styles.scss, and reference `_english-fonts` where you've specified the fonts you want. You'd do the same for the Chinese fonts.

Then, when you run Compass, you'd get two different stylesheets with all sorts of correct url goodness.

**edit for body class approach**

I think you'd want to use the "parent selector" (not sure if that's what it's called...) so your mixin for images might be something like this:

```
@mixin imageOutput($image) {
    .en & {
        background: url('http://media.domain.com/#{$image}');
    }
    .cn & {
        background: url('http://media.domain.com.cn/#{$image}');
    }
}
.class {
    @include imageOutput('file.png');
}
```

compiles to:

```
.en .class {
  background: url("http://media.domain.com/file.png");
}
.cn .class {
  background: url("http://media.domain.com.cn/file.png");
}
```

Fonts would be similar:

```
@mixin fontOutput($enFont, $cnFont) {
    .en & {
        font-family: $enFont;
    }
    .cn & {
        font-family: $cnFont;
    }
}

.item {
    @include fontOutput('comic sans ms', 'china sans ms');
}
```

compiles to:

```
.en .item {
  font-family: "comic sans ms";
}
.cn .item {
  font-family: "china sans ms";
}
```

More information on parent selectors is available here: http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand

Comment: It's an interesting approach, but this would result in having two stylesheets (which is okay, but not preferred). I was really hoping to keep it all together in one stylesheet and made it output the same css, but with different body classes.

Comment: Very interesting, however I ran into one problem, due to the way everything is build, I have to have a "main wrapper" with an ID, when using `.en &`, this gives some problems, see the following: http://pastebin.com/AYvRh3iL

Comment: Apparently this isn't possible right now, but will be supported in sass 3.3, installing the alpha release now to make sure.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work though, from what I can read it should be supported in sass 3.3

Comment: This has been available in SASS for at least two years: http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand

Comment: `&.en` will output `.mainSelector .child.en`, `.en &` will output `.en .mainSelector .child` and `.en&` won't work, the last one is what I'm looking for.